# How to remove Cutefish desktop from Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

I installed Cutefish Desktop on Ubuntu following the answer to this question : [How to install Cutefish Desktop in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346383/how-to-install-cutefish-desktop-in-ubuntu)

I got a strange desktop :( how can I remove Cutefish desktop?

Thank you

Comment: All the packages you installed, remove them one by one with `sudo apt remove packagename`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I tried this but if you see "How to install Cutefish Desktop in Ubuntu?", you will see that it is not obvious to know which packages have been installed.

Comment: You installed the .deb files (which are generated in that answer), you just remove the packages with the same names.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you for your comments. Actually,  I don't find the .deb files in the directory. The desktop seems not to be installed correctly. What I did is to create a txt file with all commands listed in that answer and then I run the command sh file.txt. Now I want to cancel all those commands...

Comment: All the .deb files are in `~/Downloads/cutefish/`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, I don't find any .deb files in that directory, see what I get when I run ls command [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NI4l0PM-GW7PThe5MZI_3qWSsPPrnykn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Each of the subdirectories, `calculator`, `filemanager`, should have a .deb file. Uninstall them individually.